# Yield n lines from a Generator class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I want to print n lines from a file everytime a Generator class is called.

I have tried the following:

```py
class FileReader:
    def __init__(self, file):
        with open(file, 'r') as fin:
            read_file = fin.read()

            # gen-comp yielding stripped lines
            lines = (line.strip() for line in read_file)
            print(lines)
```

This simply returns all the lines.

Comment: `n` lines when always called ?

Comment: Yes. For instance, first 3 lines of the file when called first time. And then the next 3 lines when called again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a `__call__` method like,

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

class FileReader:
    def __init__(self, fname, len=3):
        self.fname = fname
        self._len = len

    def __enter__(self):
        self.fd = open(self.fname, 'r')
        return self

    def __call__(self):
        return list(islice(self.fd, self._len))

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.fd:
            self.fd.close()


with FileReader(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    print(f())
    print(f())
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with class programing or generators but the following i drafted seems to fill your criteria to print x number of lines each time the object is called

```
class FileReader:
    def __init__(self, file, num_lines=10):
        fin = open(file, 'r')
        self.file_handle = fin
        self.num_lines = num_lines

    def __next__(self):
        for i in range(self.num_lines):
            yield self.file_handle.readline().strip()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.fin.close()

    def __str__(self):
        return "".join(list(next(self)))

myfile = FileReader('query4.txt', 2)
print(myfile)
print(myfile)
```

**INPUT FILE**

```
this is some data
this is other data
data is fun
data is weird
this is the 5th line
```

As you have stripped new line chars in your original program i have done the same so assume you want to concat the X lines together. If thats not the case then just remove the .strip()

**OUTPUT**

```
this is some datathis is other data
data is fundata is weird
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want a generator, and so a simple solution is just to write one directly, using `yield`.  Something like this perhaps (though it might be possible to improve the looping structure of the code):

```
def FileReader(filename, length):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        while True:
            group = []
            for i in range(length):
                try:
                    group.append(next(fin).strip())
                except StopIteration:
                    break
            if not group:
                break
            yield group
```

This then, for example, will print a list of 8 lines each time:

```
for g in FileReader(filename, 8):
    print(g)
```

Or here's an alternative that I prefer. I've knocked up an iterator building block, in the spirit of `itertools`, which groups up any Iterable into lists of a specified length.  You can then apply this directly to a file object to do what you want:

```
import itertools

def group(iterable, length):
    for key,group in itertools.groupby(
                 enumerate(iterable),
                 key=lambda elem : elem[0] // length):
        yield [elem[1] for elem in group]
```

So this can then be used to just wrap the file object like this:

```
fin = open(filename, "r")
for g in group(fin, 8):
    print([e.strip() for e in g])
```

Note that in this case, to preserve the generality of the `group` function, I've omitted the `strip` and therefore had to do it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your file object is already a generator.

```
class FileReader:
    def __init__(self, file, lines=3):
        self.fd = open(file, 'r')
        self.lines = lines

    def __call__(self):
        for i in range(self.lines):
            print(self.fd.readline())
```

This will just print empty lines when you reach the end of the file, if that's not what you want then you can try:

```
import os

class FileReader:
    def __init__(self, file, lines=3):
        self.fd = open(file, 'r')
        self.lines = lines
        self.end = self.fd.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        self.fd.seek(0)

    def __call__(self):
        for i in range(self.lines):
            if self.fd.tell() == self.end:
                print('Reached EOF')
                return
            print(self.fd.readline())
```